# "Android.process.media has stopped unexpectedly" error when I boot my Galaxy Nexus

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, crashes

Every time I boot my phone it gives the error message `android.process.media has stopped unexpectedly`. Why?

I am using 4.0.2 on my Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: Everybody (should be) up to 4.0.4 by now, if not 4.1. Is this still a problem?

Answer (score 2):

The process error you are getting is `android.process.media`
The clue is in the media part.

1. You should go to Settings > Applications > Manage Applications > Then make sure you look under the ALL tab. It is **MEDIA** what you are looking for.
2. Clear the data and cache for this one. Then Force-stop it and restart your device.

When it restarts, it should restart normal and the media will start again automatically without the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I found a fix that worked for me.

Remove the SD card, then whilst it's out, choose to clear the SD card contents,(mine allowed this). Replace the SD card and all fine, quick n easy.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd fix permissions on CWM. No help? Then try this:

1. Settings > Applications > Manage Applications >
   then make sure you look under the all tab. It is called Google Services Framework and you clear the data for this one and cache for market.
2. Go to "Settings" > Unplug your device from computer (if plugged in).
3. Choose "Manage Applications" from the list.
4. Select the "All" tab.
5. Scroll down to "Market" and select it.
6. Tap "Force stop" > "Clear cache" > Back button.
7. Scroll up to "Google Services Framework" and select it.
8. Tap "Clear data" >  "OK" > "Force stop".
9. Start Market.
10. At the "An error has occurred" message, tap "OK".
11. Hold your power button to turn off your device from the menu.
12. Turn your device back on.
13. Start Market again, and the problem should be resolved.

**Note:** "Market" is the earlier name of "Google Play Store".

Comment: I tried this and it dose not seem to have resolved the problem. I still get the error.

Comment: Do wipe data/factory reset and wipe cache in CWM. If that doesnt solve the problem flash the firmware once again

Comment: You can factory reset even from the stock recovery. BTW who said a word about custom ROMs?

Answer (score 1):

Removing my sd card helps, I'll try to reinsert it again.

Answer (score 0):

The process name implies that it is related to SD card. FAT filesystem is very old and unreliable filesystem. Android stop apps to prevent further damage to your data.

Solution: Eject MicroSD card. Insert in card reader, plug to PC. Run `chkdsk i: /f /x`, where `i`- drive letter for your SD partition in Windows OS. `Chkdsk` shall find and fix the problem. Problem solved.